# Mixture of predictions

Tags: regression, estimation, inference, prediction

I am trying to solve the following problem. There might be a straightforward solution, but I am struggling to find it. The problem is roughly as follows: I have a large dataset of estimates on the lenght of a stick, made by kids of different ages. However, different kids with different ages were involved for each observation. I am trying to make a optimal consensus prediction. I could of course use e.g. the mean or the median . However, I am trying wondering if one can find a better rule (using RSME as loss function) that incorporates and adjusts for the age of the children. Any thoughts or advice much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: In principal, you could do weighted least squares: assign higher weight to the less noisy observations (eg. observations of older kids). That said, do we know the older kids are better? How much better? Do we know how variance of the error varies with age?